# Why passing $event in Angular (when dealing with DOM events) is a dubious practice

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I was reading Angular 2 documentation [where I found](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html):

> **Passing the $event is not a good practice**
>
> Typing the event object reveals a significant objection to passing the
>   entire DOM event into the method: the component has too much awareness
>   of the template details. It can't extract information without knowing
>   more than it should about the HTML implementation. That breaks the
>   separation of concerns between the template (what the user sees) and
>   the component (how the application processes user data).

For some reason I can't exactly fit my head around what it says. Seems like there are no explanation available either anywhere.

Can someone explain the exact meaning of this in simpler terms (with an example, if possible)?

Comment: Could you expand on what you do and don't understand there? For example, do you know what *"separation of concerns"* means? Have you looked at the next section, which gives an example of the suggested way of doing things, to see how that differs?

Comment: @jonsharpe Well what I do understand from separation of concern is an entity should be restricted to do its own job and should not interfere where it should not. However, if I pass an event to component, all I am passing is an object which contains data about a single node. Is it really that bad?

Comment: Ya I saw at the next section and understood it very well. What I wanted to know is what risk am I taking with the first approach.

Comment: added a clarification to the title - passing $event is only a dubious practice when $event refers to a DOM event. If it's a custom event emitter, then $event will be an object in the domain, and it's perfectly fine then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the examples the docs already provide for before and after:

> ```ts
> @Component({
>   selector: 'key-up1',
>   template: `
>     <input #box (keyup)="onKey($event)">
>     <p>{{values}}</p>
>   `
> })
> export class KeyUpComponent_v1 {
>   values = ''; 
>
>   onKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
>     this.values += (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value + ' | ';
>   }
> }
> ```

Here the *component* has to know that the event has a target, which is an input element, which has a value. Now v2:

> ```ts
> @Component({
>   selector: 'key-up2',
>   template: `
>     <input #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">
>     <p>{{values}}</p>
>   `
> })
> export class KeyUpComponent_v2 {
>   values = '';
>
>   onKey(value: string) {
>     this.values += value + ' | ';
>   }
> }
> ```

Here the *template* is responsible for extracting the correct value from its own structure, and all the component knows is that it's getting a string. Now imagine:

1. You need to change the `input` element to a `select`, to restrict the range of inputs. What has to change in each version? Just the template, or does the component have to change too?
2. You want to test the handling method. How easy is this for each version? Can you just pass in a string, or do you have to build an event with an element of the appropriate structure?

This is what separation of concerns really means - how far does a change propagate? How much does each piece of your system need to know about the other pieces to continue working? Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), for example:

> Of special value is the ability to later improve or modify one section
>   of code without having to know the details of other sections, and
>   without having to make corresponding changes to those sections.

---

However, as [snorkpete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11742/snorkpete) suggests, note that the reservation around passing `$event` to component methods only applies when `$event` refers to DOM events. In the case where you're using an `EventEmitter` to raise your own events, `$event` will (most likely) be an object from the business domain, and is perfectly fine to use as is.

Comment: Makes definitely more sense to me now. For some reasons, I was contemplating it to be more of a harmful practice rather a bad design. Thanks for your time.